# Is law of demeter aplied to properties too?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, law-of-demeter

Law of demeter says that an object can't invoke a method M from an object B from an object A.
But is it aplied to properties too? Example?

```
public class B{
     public bool IsValid();
}

public class A{
     public B B{get;set;}
}
```

Can I do something like that?

```
var isValid = new A().B.IsValid()
```

or should I do this:

```
public class B{
     public bool IsValid();
}

public class A{
     private B B{get;set;}

     public bool IsValid(){
          return B.IsValid();
     }
}

var result = new A().IsValid();
```

Is there a problem(according to law) if I access a B's method from A?

Comment: In your 2d example, it looks that the instance of `B` created by `A` inside it. In your 1st example, it is a public property by which `B` can be set. What is your exact scenario so that it is becoming necessary for you to call `A.B.IsValid` as against `B.IsValid`? In your 2nd example, the `get` can be public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it applies to properties as well, since the client of this code:

```
var isValid = new A().B.IsValid();
```

is coupled to `A` and also to `B`.

When fixing the law of Demeter violations, you have to balance the need for decoupling and the need to keep responsibilities clearly separated. Sometimes you can create Demeter transmogrifiers: classes that have too many unrelated methods just to comply with the law of Demeter.

**Update**: An example of a Demeter transmogrifier can be found in [this post](http://securesoftwaredev.com/2008/06/16/the-law-of-demeter/):

> Consider, for example, someone who’s trying to kiss up to his boss: `sendFlowers(john.getManager().getSpouse())`. Applying Hide Delegate here would yield a `getManagersSpouse()` method in Employee. Yuck.

Comment: What if the code is like `var someB = new A().B; bool isValid = someB.IsValid();`?

Comment: So, in my second example the A class would be a transmogrifier, correct?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: The law of Demeter is about coupling. If the client needs to know about a dependency of `A` (`B` in this case) that he usually shouldn't know about, then that's a violation.

Comment: @MuriloKunze: Not necessarily. It will only be a transmogrifier if the resulting fix of the violation creates uncohesive code.

Comment: @MuriloKunze: added an example.